# Deleting of an item, indexing problem...

Tags: javascript

```
for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
   deleteButton[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                    AddPatientVitalsModel.globalData.splice(i, 1);
    });
}
```

When i click on a button, a new table is added... i change some information in table and again add another table... and i delete this table... but the array value does delete the first index alone.

The Value of **i** is always zero and it deletes the first item in the Array. How can i ensure that for each table it has different ID.

For each click i feel so that i value always starts from Zero....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overwriting the value of `i` at each loop. You could use an anonymous function to pass the variable by value:

```
for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    (function(i){ //i is now defined within the scope of this anonymous function
        deleteButton[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            AddPatientVitalsModel.globalData.splice(i, 1);
        }, true);
    })(i); //Pass i to the anonymous function
}
```

Note that `i` can have a different name inside the anonymous function, without making a difference.

ANother notice: Pass three arguments to `addEventListener`, because many browsers will throw an error if the third argument is omitted.

Comment: how will it work, i am compling my app.. will the correct index of i would be passed

Comment: *"How will it work"*? I'v eonly added two additional lines in your code. Read the answer + JavaScript comments. If it's still unclear, ask a more specific question.

Comment: But here is another thing. If you delete item from middle of array, button index will be different from array indexes.

Comment: Solution: Instead of removing the element from the array globalData, set the value to null: `APVM.globalData[i] = null`.

Answer (score 1):

Because **i** scope is outside event. You need get index from variable e, or maybe work this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
   var ii = i;
   deleteButton[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                    AddPatientVitalsModel.globalData.splice(ii, 1);
    });
}
```

But I am not sure it works on javascript.

Comment: @newworld: but will the value of ii keep on changing on each click, my issue is it always deletes the first item in the array

Comment: Your solution does not work because there is no new scope. You would need to create a function to make the variable "freeze", since only functions define a new scope.